# ServiceStack - customize auth response

Tags: authentication, servicestack, response

ServiceStack - customize auth response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the [AuthenticateResponse](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/c646209ea270bd4fd18bd20df9f39ddbe69555a8/src/ServiceStack.Client/AuthDtos.cs#L33) and [ResponseStatus](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/c646209ea270bd4fd18bd20df9f39ddbe69555a8/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/ResponseStatus.cs#L13) DTO's contain a `Meta` string Dictionary which you can use to add additional data to.

You can modify the returned AuthenticateResponse DTO with a [Response Filter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters) or overriding the `OnAfterExecute()` method in your AppHost.

#### Using a Global ResponseFilter

```
this.GlobalResponseFilters.Add((req, res, responseDto) => {
    var authResponse = responseDto as AuthenticateResponse;
    if (authResponse != null) {
        authResponse.Meta = new Dictionary<string,string> { 
            {"foo", "bar"} 
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please clarify a bit on how to utilize this 'Meta' string Dictionary? Do I need to override authenticate method in provider or?

Comment: @user5506787 it's just a normal `Dictionary<string,string>`, populate it with any key/value pairs you want.

Comment: HI, tried both approaches but no luck. public override object OnAfterExecute(IRequest req, object requestDto, object response)
        {
            var authResponse = response.GetDto<AuthenticateResponse>();
            if (authResponse != null)
            {
                authResponse.Meta = new Dictionary<string, string> {
            {"foo", "bar"}
        };
            }
            return authResponse;
        }

Comment: Can I ask should i put the above global response filter right inside Configure()? I read the request & response filter page, it seems so to me. But I didn't get the result. :(

Comment: @user5506787 Yeah all configuration goes in AppHost.Configre(), I've just tested this and it's working as expected. Why are you using different code than what my example shows? Filters/callbacks gets called for every request, if you don't check the response type it gets applied to every response. `GetDto<T>` is for getting the underlying Response DTO not the inner ResponseStatus, you can use the `T.GetResponseStatus()` extension method for that, but you don't want to since you only want to do this for `AuthenticateResponse`.